# SwiftUI : How I can maintain onReceive when the View in closed

Tags: swiftui, timer, combine

```
    import SwiftUI


struct TimerView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var tm : TimerModel
    
    @State var timerStyle : TimerStyle?
    @State var focusColors : [Color] = [Color.green, Color.mint, Color.green, Color.mint, Color.green]
    @State var breakColors : [Color] = [Color.blue, Color.mint, Color.blue, Color.mint, Color.blue]
    @State var longBreakColors : [Color] = [Color.gray, Color.white, Color.gray, Color.white, Color.gray]
    @State var isShowNewTimerView : Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                Color("BackgroundColor").ignoresSafeArea(.all)
                if tm.timerStyle == nil {
                    NoTimerView()
                } else {
                    VStack(alignment : .center, spacing: 40){
                        Spacer()
                        if let timerStyle = tm.timerStyle {
                            switch timerStyle {
                                case .focus:
                                    Text("Focus Mode ")
                                        .font(.system(size: 30, weight: .bold, design: .rounded))
                                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                       
                                case .short:
                                    Text("Break Mode ☕️")
                                        .font(.system(size: 30, weight: .bold, design: .rounded))
                                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                             
                                case .long:
                                    Text("Long Break Mode ")
                                        .font(.system(size: 30, weight: .bold, design: .rounded))
                                        .fontWeight(.bold)//
                                    }
                                }
                        
                    if let timerStyle = tm.timerStyle {
                            switch timerStyle {
                            case .focus:
                                ProgressView(progress: tm.progress, gradientColors: focusColors, time: formatTime())
                                    .padding()
                                    .onReceive(tm.timer) { _ in
                                        if tm.timerMode == .start {
                                            if tm.elapsedFocusTime != 0 {
                                                tm.trackFocusProgress()
                                            } else {
                                                if tm.isAuto {
                                                    tm.timerStyle = .short
                                                    tm.progress = 0
                                                    tm.elapsedShortTime = tm.totalShortTime
                                                    
                                                    if tm.isOnSound {
                                                        playSound(sound: "chimeup", type: "mp3")
                                                    }
                                                } else {
                                                    tm.timerMode = .normal
                                                    tm.timerStyle = .short
                                                    tm.isStarted = false
                                                    tm.progress = 0
                                                    tm.elapsedShortTime = tm.totalShortTime
                                                    audioPlayer1?.stop()
                                                    
                                                    if tm.isOnSound {
                                                        playSound(sound: "chimeup", type: "mp3")
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                            case .short:
                                ProgressView(progress: tm.progress, gradientColors: breakColors, time: formatTime())
                                    .padding()
                                    .onReceive(tm.timer) { _ in
                                        if tm.timerMode == .start {
                                            if tm.elapsedShortTime != 0 {
                                                tm.trackFocusProgress()
                                            } else {
                                                if tm.isAuto {
                                                    if tm.isSkipMode {
                                                        tm.timerStyle = .focus
                                                        tm.progress = 0
                                                        tm.elapsedFocusTime = tm.totalFocusTime
                                                        
                                                        if tm.isOnSound {
                                                            playSound(sound: "chimeup", type: "mp3")
                                                        }
                                                        
                                                    } else {
                                                        tm.timerStyle = .long
                                                        tm.progress = 0
                                                        tm.elapsedLongBreakTime = tm.totalLongBreakTime
                                                        if tm.isOnSound {
                                                            playSound(sound: "chimeup", type: "mp3")
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                } else {
                                                    if tm.isSkipMode {
                                                        tm.timerStyle = .focus
                                                        tm.timerMode = .normal
                                                        tm.timerStyle = .focus
                                                        tm.isStarted = false
                                                        tm.progress = 0
                                                        tm.elapsedFocusTime = tm.totalFocusTime
                                                        audioPlayer1?.stop()
                                                        
                                                        if tm.isOnSound {
                                                            playSound(sound: "chimeup", type: "mp3")
                                                        }
                                                        
                                                    } else {
                                                        tm.timerMode = .normal
                                                        tm.timerStyle = .long
                                                        tm.isStarted = false
                                                        tm.progress = 0
                                                        tm.elapsedLongBreakTime = tm.totalLongBreakTime
                                                        audioPlayer1?.stop()
                                                        
                                                        if tm.isOnSound {
                                                            playSound(sound: "chimeup", type: "mp3")
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                            case .long:
                                ProgressView(progress: tm.progress, gradientColors: longBreakColors, time: formatTime())
                                    .padding()
                                    .onReceive(tm.timer) { _ in
                                        if tm.timerMode == .start {
                                            if tm.elapsedLongBreakTime != 0 {
                                                tm.trackFocusProgress()
                                            } else {
                                                if tm.isAuto {
                                                    tm.timerStyle = .focus
                                                    tm.progress = 0
                                                    tm.elapsedFocusTime = tm.totalFocusTime
                                                    
                                                    if tm.isOnSound {
                                                        playSound(sound: "chimeup", type: "mp3")
                                                    }
                                                    
                                                } else {
                                                    tm.timerMode = .normal
                                                    tm.timerStyle = .focus
                                                    tm.isStarted = false
                                                    tm.progress = 0
                                                    tm.elapsedFocusTime = tm.totalFocusTime
                                                    audioPlayer1?.stop()
                                                    
                                                    if tm.isOnSound {
                                                        playSound(sound: "chimeup", type: "mp3")
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                        }
                    }
                    
                    if let timerStyle = tm.timerStyle {
                        switch timerStyle {
                        case .focus:
                            Text("Let's concentrate on your task!")
                                .font(.headline)
                                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                        case .short:
                            Text("Well done, Have a short break!")
                                .font(.headline)
                                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                        case .long:
                            Text("It's so long journey, take care yourself.")
                                .font(.headline)
                                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                        }
                    }
                    
                    HStack {
                    
                    Button(action: {
                        switch tm.timerMode {
                            
                        case .normal:
                            tm.timerMode = .start
                            tm.isStarted.toggle()
                            tm.backBroundMusic()
                            
                        case .start:
                            audioPlayer1?.stop()
                            tm.timerMode = .normal
                            
                            if let timerStyle = tm.timerStyle {
                                switch timerStyle {
                                case .focus:
                                    tm.progress = 0
                                    tm.elapsedFocusTime = tm.totalFocusTime
                                    
                                case .short:
                                    tm.progress = 0
                                    tm.elapsedShortTime = tm.totalShortTime
                                   
                                case .long:
                                    tm.progress = 0
                                    tm.elapsedLongBreakTime = tm.totalLongBreakTime
                                }
                            }
                            
                            tm.isStarted.toggle()
                            
                        case .pause:
        
                            tm.isStarted.toggle()
                            tm.isPaused.toggle()
                            tm.timerMode = .normal
                            
                            if let timerStyle = tm.timerStyle {
                                switch timerStyle {
                                case .focus:
                                    tm.progress = 0
                                    tm.elapsedFocusTime = tm.totalFocusTime
                                    
                                case .short:
                                    tm.progress = 0
                                    tm.elapsedShortTime = tm.totalShortTime
                                   
                                case .long:
                                    tm.progress = 0
                                    tm.elapsedLongBreakTime = tm.totalLongBreakTime
                                }
                            }
                            
                        case .stop:
                            tm.timerMode = .normal
                        }
                    }, label: {
                        Image(systemName: tm.isStarted ? "square.fill":"play.fill")
                            .frame(width : 60, height : 60)
                            .background(tm.isStarted ? .red : .green)
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .font(.title)
                            .cornerRadius(10)
                            .shadow(color: .gray.opacity(0.5), radius: 1, x: 1, y: 1)
                    })
                    .disabled(tm.timerStyle == nil)
                    .padding()
                        
                    Button(action:  {
                        switch tm.timerMode {
                        case .normal:
                            return
                        case .start:
                            audioPlayer1?.stop()
                            tm.timerMode = .pause
                            tm.isPaused.toggle()
                        case .pause:
                            tm.backBroundMusic()
                            tm.timerMode = .start
                            tm.isPaused.toggle()
                        case .stop:
                            return
                        }
                    }, label: {
                        Image(systemName: tm.timerMode == .pause
                              ? "play.fill" : "pause.fill")
                            .frame(width : 60, height : 60)
                            .background(tm.timerMode == .normal ? .gray : .yellow)
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .font(.title)
                            .cornerRadius(10)
                            .shadow(color: .gray.opacity(0.5), radius: 1, x: 1, y: 1)
                    })
                    .disabled(tm.timerStyle == nil)
                    .padding()
                        
                    Button(action:  {
                        
                        audioPlayer1?.stop()
                        
                        if let timerStyle = tm.timerStyle {
                            switch timerStyle {
                            case .focus:
                                tm.timerMode = .normal
                                tm.timerStyle = .short
                                tm.isStarted = false
                                tm.progress = 0
                                tm.elapsedShortTime = tm.totalShortTime
                            case .short:
                                if tm.isSkipMode {
                                    tm.timerMode = .normal
                                    tm.timerStyle = .focus
                                    tm.isStarted = false
                                    tm.progress = 0
                                    tm.elapsedFocusTime = tm.totalFocusTime
                                } else {
                                    tm.timerMode = .normal
                                    tm.timerStyle = .long
                                    tm.isStarted = false
                                    tm.progress = 0
                                    tm.elapsedLongBreakTime = tm.totalLongBreakTime
                                }
                            case .long:
                                tm.timerMode = .normal
                                tm.timerStyle = .focus
                                tm.isStarted = false
                                tm.progress = 0
                                tm.elapsedFocusTime = tm.totalFocusTime
                            }
                        }
                    }, label: {
                        Image(systemName: "forward.end.fill")
                            .frame(width : 60, height : 60)
                            .background(.blue)
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .font(.title)
                            .cornerRadius(10)
                            .shadow(color: .gray.opacity(0.5), radius: 1, x: 1, y: 1)
                    })
                    .disabled(tm.timerStyle == nil)
                    .padding()
                        
                    } // hst
                    Spacer()
                }//vst
            }
        }//Zstack
                    .navigationTitle("PPO.MO ⏱")
                    .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
                    .navigationBarItems(trailing:
                       HStack{
                        
                        if tm.isOnBackgroundSound {
                            Menu {
                                Button(action: {
                                    switch tm.timerMode {
                                    case .normal:
                                        tm.backgroundNoise = .forest
                                    case .start:
                                        tm.backgroundNoise = .forest
                                        tm.backBroundMusic()
                                    case .pause:
                                        audioPlayer1?.stop()
                                    case .stop:
                                        tm.backgroundNoise = .forest
                                    }
                                    
                                }, label: {
                                    Label(tm.backgroundNoise == .forest ? "✅ Forest" : "Forest", systemImage: "leaf")
                                })
                                
                                Button(action: {
                                    switch tm.timerMode {
                                    case .normal:
                                        tm.backgroundNoise = .river
                                    case .start:
                                        tm.backgroundNoise = .river
                                        tm.backBroundMusic()
                                    case .pause:
                                        audioPlayer1?.stop()
                                    case .stop:
                                        tm.backgroundNoise = .river
                                    }
                                }, label: {
                                    Label(tm.backgroundNoise == .river ? "✅ River" : "River", systemImage: "drop.circle")
                                })
                                
                                Button(action: {
                                    switch tm.timerMode {
                                    case .normal:
                                        tm.backgroundNoise = .rain
                                    case .start:
                                        tm.backgroundNoise = .rain
                                        tm.backBroundMusic()
                                    case .pause:
                                        audioPlayer1?.stop()
                                    case .stop:
                                        tm.backgroundNoise = .rain
                                    }
                                }, label: {
                                    Label(tm.backgroundNoise == .rain ? "✅ Rain" : "Rain", systemImage: "cloud.rain")
                                })
                                
                                Button(action: {
                                    switch tm.timerMode {
                                    case .normal:
                                        tm.backgroundNoise = .wave
                                    case .start:
                                        tm.backgroundNoise = .wave
                                        tm.backBroundMusic()
                                    case .pause:
                                        audioPlayer1?.stop()
                                    case .stop:
                                        tm.backgroundNoise = .wave
                                    }
                                }, label: {
                                    Label(tm.backgroundNoise == .wave ? "✅ Wave" : "Wave", systemImage: "cloud.rain")
                                })
                                
                                Button(action: {
                                    tm.backgroundNoise = .turnOff
                                    audioPlayer1?.stop()
                                }, label: {
                                    Label(tm.backgroundNoise == .turnOff ? "✅ Turn off" : "Turn off", systemImage: "speaker.slash")
                                })
                                
                            } label: {
                                Image(systemName: tm.backgroundNoise == .turnOff ? "speaker.slash.circle" : "speaker.circle")
                            }
                        }
                        
                        NavigationLink(destination: {
                            AddTimerView()
                        }, label: {
                            Image(systemName: "plus")
                        })
                        .simultaneousGesture(TapGesture().onEnded({
                            tm.timerMode = .pause
                            audioPlayer1?.stop()
                        }))
                    })
        }//nav
    }
}

extension TimerView {
    
    func formatTime() -> String {
        
        if let timerStyle = tm.timerStyle {
            switch timerStyle {
            case .focus:
                let minute = Int(tm.elapsedFocusTime) / 60 % 60
                let second = Int(tm.elapsedFocusTime) % 60
                
                return String(format: "%02i:%02i", minute, second)
            case .short:
                let minute = Int(tm.elapsedShortTime) / 60 % 60
                let second = Int(tm.elapsedShortTime) % 60
                
                return String(format: "%02i:%02i", minute, second)
            case .long:
                let minute = Int(tm.elapsedLongBreakTime) / 60 % 60
                let second = Int(tm.elapsedLongBreakTime) % 60
                
                return String(format: "%02i:%02i", minute, second)
            }
        }
            return "00:00"
    }
}
```

Hi, I am trying to make pomodoro timer myself.

But, when I checked bugs, I found that my onReceive modifier is turned off when the view is closed by swipe up.

When did that, timer is stopped and I think the onReceive is not working.

So, I want to know how I can maintain onreceive even if the view is swipe down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put onReceive on some always-shown view, like

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        ZStack {
            Color("BackgroundColor").ignoresSafeArea(.all)
                 .onReceive(tm.timer) { _ in               // << here !!
```

from handling purpose it does not matter where it is used.

Comment: Firstly, Thank you for your helping! Um, I asked like fool. It meant If the app is closed. for example, the user wants to do the other thing, they will swipe up the app, right? but during this time, the timer is not working. and when the user some back to app, it starts works.

Comment: You need to use background tasks and that topic is completely unrelated to SwiftUI.